# Select where either column value but not both

Tags: mysql, sql

There's a table T0 that looks like this and using MySQL 5.7. Am storing ids in `id`, text in C1, and NULL or integers in C2 - NULL being the default value. An entry in C1 can have multiple values in C2. If you know about Closure tables, you'll notice that this table is slightly different in that the C1 entries do not correspond to id entries.

```
id | C1 | C2
---+----+-----
1  | a  | NULL
2  | b  | NULL
3  | c  | NULL
4  | c  | 3
5  | c  | 5
6  | d  | NULL
```

C1's value is stored in C2. The table is set such that C1 cannot have duplicate values in C2. So c, for example, cannot have two 3s. So the table is unique that way.

Would like to have a query return all rows where field C1 value is 3 and if C1 value is not 3, return row where C1 value is NULL.

Have tried the following code but to no avail.

```
SELECT *
FROM T0
WHERE C2 = 3 OR C2 IS NULL
```

So the query should be able to return 1, 2, 4 and 6. The desired result is:

```
id | C1 | C2
---+----+-----
1  | a  | NULL
2  | b  | NULL
4  | c  | 3
6  | d  | NULL
```

Comment: What data type are you storing in C2 ?

Comment: There is some confusion in your question. Did you mean that you want to find values of C1 for which there exists a row with C2 = 3 _or_ there exists a row with C2 IS NULL? Be clear.

Comment: Also it seems like this kind of approach is antithetical to how tables are supposed to be used. Perhaps you can explain your _real_ goal while you're at it!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit just polished it up. Actually I don't see it as antithetical. The NULL is the default value. C1 can have multiple values in C2 - more like a 1 to many relationship.

Comment: `Which query can I use to return id values 1,2,4 and 6 (Where C2 is either 3 or NULL)?` - What about row with id=3 ?

Comment: I don't understand your question at all, mine logical sense would say your result should/would be the records where id = 1, 2 and 6  because C2 for the group C1 = 2 has both C2 = NULL and C2 = 3.. that is what your are asking with *"Would like to have a query return rows where table field C1 value is either 3 or NULL, but not both."*

Comment: @RaymondNijland Sorry about that. I've updated the question. Been coding for hours so tired. Hope the brush up helps.

Comment: what about "ties"? what should happen for example if C1 `a` has two `C2` records with `NULL`?

Comment: @RaymondNijland The table is set such that ties can't happen. Already tested and already carrying data.

Comment: Ok that's a bit clearer. So you want to return rows with C2 value 3, and rows with C2 value NULL that do not have a corresponding row (via C1) with value 3. We can work with that (although it still seems like a somewhat strange table layout)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Exactly! Thanks for the questions. They've helped me in updating my question.

Comment: No problem! Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check that condition using `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT *
FROM t
WHERE (
    C2 = 3
) OR (
    C2 IS NULL AND NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT 1
        FROM t AS x
        WHERE x.C1 = t.C1 AND x.C2 = 3
    )
)
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to reform this into a join but yep

Comment: Looks good here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=07a1580321d8eec092bf92afafccc87d

Comment: @SalmanA in the fiddle it works. I've examined the code and it should work and most people would have no issue with it. In my database it takes 5ms execution and 5ms fetching which is good. But can't seem to understand why it won't work as expected in my database but returns all rows except id #5. Could you have an alternative implementation?

Comment: No idea, perhaps you messed up the aliases used inside the subquery (x and t) e.g. `WHERE C1 = t.C1 AND t.C2 = 3` is incorrect and it'll produce 5 rows instead of 4. I'll revise the query and explicitly specify the aliases as they should be.

Comment: It worked. Thanks Salman A for your help and sincerity and thanks to @LightnessRacesinOrbit in pointing me to your answer. It turns out C1 had not been indexed so a 'NOT EXISTS' wasn't working as expected. Table has over 12,000 records. Just made a small work-around by adding a left join to another table in the sub-query you provided and am back on track. The table was unnecessary for this purpose but C1 wasn't responding as needed. Thanks for your time also. Will test all the other answers and give them an answer also.

Comment: That doesn't sound right, @John. Indexing doesn't affect the result, only the performance.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's true indexing only affects performance. But that's in most cases. Complex setups like this one is something else. That was the bit I could disclose without giving away the entire setup.

Comment: No, it's in all cases. Your "setup" is not complex enough to violate fundamentals. You made a mistake in your observations.

Answer (score 1):

This is a simpler approach and would be faster than doing a join when there are a lot of rows in the table.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM T0 
 WHERE (C2 = 3) 
    OR (C2 IS NULL AND 
        C1 NOT IN (SELECT C1 FROM T0 WHERE C2 = 3))
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you have to display the ID? If not, then this gets easy-peasy:

```
select c1, max(c2)
from t0
where c2 = 3 or c2 is null
group by c1
order by c1;
```

Comment: Yes, IDs are required since they are going to be used as foreign keys in another table.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a `UNION`?

```
SELECT * FROM t0 where C2=3 
UNION 
SELECT * FROM t0 where C2 IS NULL AND C1 NOT IN (SELECT C1 FROM t0 WHERE C2<>3) ORDER BY id;
```